# Understanding the covariant derivative and its relation to parallel transport

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields, covariance

I have been reading section 3.1 of Wald's GR book in which he introduces the notion of a covariant derivative. As I understand, this is introduced as the (partial) derivative operators $\partial_{a}$ are dependent on the coordinate system one chooses and thus not naturally associated with the structure of the manifold, therefore we introduce a new derivative operator $\nabla_{a}$ which fulfils this criteria. Intuitively, the covariant derivative is constructed in such a way as to remove any artefacts arising from any particular coordinate system, such that the rate of change of a tensor field in a direction along the manifold is itself a tensor field. Is this correct?

He then goes on to say that a vector $\mathbf{v}^{a}$ given at each point along a curve $C$ (with tangent vector $\mathbf{t}^{a}$) is said to be *parallely transported* as one moves along the curve if the equation $$\mathbf{t}^{a}\nabla_{a}\mathbf{v}^{b}=0$$ is satisfied along the curve.
Intuitively, is this a statement that a vector $\mathbf{v}^{a}$ is parallely transported along the curve if it remains *constant* as it moves along the curve, this can be translated into the mathematical statement that its directional derivative along the curve vanishes, i.e. $\mathbf{t}^{a}\nabla_{a}\mathbf{v}^{b}=0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: Questions which can be answered with a simple *Yes* aren't good questions.

Comment: Apologies, I'm just trying to get an understanding of the notion really and thought it might be useful to express my thoughts on the matter so far.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, *parallel transport*, *covariant derivative* and *connection* are all synonym for you can recover one from the other. So given a manifold one usually starts by giving one notion (e.g. how a vector field is transported parallel to itself along a family of curves) and then, if needed, the other objects are derived. In physics, when dealing with a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold, one makes use of the Levi-Civita, or torsion-free metric connection, which in terms of coordinates is completely specified by the Christoffel symbols (which are not tensor quantities alone).